# Paypal Unsubscribe return url

Tags: paypal, return, unsubscribe

I have created a paypal Unsubscribe button in Java , when user click on it and after login to paypal account and unsubscribes , the paypal posts on the notifyurl successfully and i am able to update my database.But i want to return to my site after unsubscription. But not able to do so.

Is there any way so that i can return to my site,to display the GUI.

The unsubscribe button code paypal has only provided me with following url
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_subscr-find&alias=sellr1_1252495907_biz%40gmail%2ecom

The notify url is my servlet.

Thanks in advance.

-Zeeshan

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is always some kind of return URL parameter in the paypal api. Have you searched for that in the documentation?

Comment: There is a return URL parameter for subscription button(and its working for subscription), but not in unsubscription button. also unsubscription doesn't invoke the return url parameter mentioned in the subscription button.

Comment: Strange. usually they're not that bad when they design their apis. I'd ask in the paypal dev forum, maybe a paypal dev answers.

Answer (score -1):

The parameters you want are the Success URL and Cancel URL.  When you setup your [Subscription button](https://www.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_button-designer&factory_type=subscribe), open up the "Step 3: Customize advanced features" option.   There, you'll see two checkboxes with input fields, one for the URL you want people to go to if they cancel the subscription, and one for if the agree to the payments.

Comment: The user is looking for a way to redirect after Unsubscribe (not cancel or accept a subscription)